# One Click Publish Application with different configurations

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, publish, oneclick

I've written a small c# winforms application that I would like to one click publish to a location so users can download and install. I've managed to set it up ok with no problems, but I've now come to a problem. - using both VS 2012 & 2013.

I've created a new compile configuration called "test" (debug|release|test). I use XML SlowCheetah plugin so that it allows me to have multiple App.Config files so I can put different settings in them based on the configuration selected when compiled.

I now want to publish the "test" app to a different location (test server) but when I go to the one click publish option the configurations are disabled.

How can I enable these so I can publish the different configurations to different locations? I don't really want to be editing the app.config files and the publish paths every time.

Comment: Have you checked out the info on [How to: Use ClickOnce to Deploy Applications That Can Run on Multiple Versions of the .NET Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee517334.aspx)

Comment: @chaddienhart Thanks for the comment, I want to target the same .net version (4.5) I need to have the publish to publish different configurations to different servers. each configuration uses the same .net version, it's things like the app.config file that is different due to "slowcheetah" plugin